# c++: how to shuffle a dynamic array of pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct

I am shuffling songs for my program but im a little confused because when  I try the compiler tells me I cant compare my struct to an int. Im wondering what yall might think?

```
struct Songs                 //my struct
{
string title;     
string artist;
string mem;  
};

Songs *ptr;
ptr = new Songs[25];    //dynamic array
```

so i told u the struct and ptr well heres the function im experiencing trouble..

```
void shuffle (Songs song[], Songs *ptr, string title, string mem, string  artist, int num)
{

 for (int i=0; i<(num); i++) 
 {
     int r = i + (rand() % (num-i)); // Random remaining position.
     int temp = ptr[i]; ptr[i] = ptr[r]; ptr[r] = temp;  //this isnt working
 }                                                     //but its logically sound?   

 for (int c=0; c<n; c++) 
 {
     cout << ptr[c] << " ";  // Just print 
 }      
}
```

Comment: This is *not* an array of pointers. Also, you’ve got a lot of unused arguments in your function. Intentionally?

Comment: ah apologies for the unused args

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The offending code is at `int temp = ptr[i]; ... ptr[r] = temp;`, you're assigning `Song`  and `int` which is not possible.

**Additionally**, I strongly suggest using `std::vector< Song >` for storage. Your code is more robust and will crash less likely, plus the vector always knows the number of Songs it contains. Example

```
#include <vector>
...
struct Song { ... };
...
void shuffle(std::vector< Song >& mySongs, ...)
{
   /* shuffle mySongs somehow. */
   ...
}
```

`mySongs.size()` contains the number of songs, and you can access each song with `mySongs[index]` (or better `mySongs.at(index)`) as expected. Adding new songs is done by `mySongs.push_back(someSong)`.

**Now to your question**: How do I shuffle my vector of songs. Well ...

```
/* at start of program. */
srand(unsigned(time(NULL)));
...
void shuffle(std::vector< Song >& mySongs)
{
    std::random_shuffle(mySongs.begin(), mySongs.end());
}
```

does the trick. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6926502/589206).

Writing a song to a stream can be done by defining a function like this:

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& osr, const Song& mySong)
{
    osr << mySong.title << ' ' << mySong.artitst << ' ' << mySong.mem;
    return osr;
}
```

Now you can happily do `std::cout << mySong << std::endl`.

Comment: thnx for this help ..it now shuffles great but vectors are new to me. do i cout them as i would regular arrays? for example:           for (int i=0; i<num; i++)
    {
     cout << song[num].title << song[num].artist << song[num].mem;
    }      does not work after the shuffle

Comment: Should work as expected. Even better, you can give your Song object a function that writes it to a stream. I'll add to my answer in a few.

Comment: thnx again. idk why we arent taught vectors but they seem so much simpler. i am gonna study these on my own now because they seem incredibly useful.

Comment: Possibly the goal of your course is to learn how to use pointers, in this case they might object if you use a `vector` instead. But for practical purposes `vector` is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You should really try to use more out of the standard library. With std::vector and std::random_shuffle this would be so much cleaner.
Edit: Code now with output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct song
{
    std::string title;     
    std::string artist;
    std::string mem;  
};

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& stream, const song& s)
{
    return stream << "Song: { Title: " << s.title 
        << ", Artist: " << s.artist << ", Mem: " << s.mem;
}

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& stream, const std::vector<T>& v)
{
    stream << '[';
    for (auto i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i)
        stream << *i << ", \n";
    return stream << ']';
}
int main()
{
    std::vector<song> songs;
    // .push_back your songs
    std::random_shuffle(songs.begin(), songs.end());
    std::cout << songs;
}
```

Comment: wow interesting ..we've not gotten to vectors but this seems so simple. do i pass vector<song> to the function as well? thnx again

Comment: Well, the vector is basicly your dynamic array, but you don't need to bother with manual resizing/freeing etc. - random_shuffle is a template function, you pass in iterators, begin points to the first and end after the last element.

Comment: thank u cooky. would u suggest i cout<< vector<song>   to write the shuffle?

Comment: I edited the code. It shows the idea, you can of course change the formatting as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign a `Songs` object to an `int` (`int temp = ptr[i];`), and then you try to assign an `int` to a `Songs` (`ptr[r] = temp;`). That will not work. To make it work, I suggest you change the line to:
    `Songs temp = ptr[i]; ptr[i] = ptr[r]; ptr[r] = temp;`

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
int temp = ptr[i]; ptr[i] = ptr[r]; ptr[r] = temp;
```

to

```
Songs temp = ptr[i]; ptr[i] = ptr[r]; ptr[r] = temp;
```

Your original code tries to assign a `Songs` to an integer. You need to create a temporary of the same type as the object you are trying to assign it.

Comment: Better yet, just use `std::swap(ptr[i], ptr[r])`.

Comment: Better still to use `std::vector` and `std::random_shuffle( v.begin(), v.end() )` to do the entire thing, but that's not really what the question is about :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, why are you using an `int` to store the struct value? Just make it:

```
Songs temp;
```

Also, your type names are totally confusing, `Songs` seems to represent a *single* song.

Comment: ah apolgies structs seems to me to hold all the songs while 1 song is for each data thnx again