# Generate random numbers exaclty once

Tags: c++, random

I need to create a set of random numbers between 0 and 800. The problem is at the moment that I need to do this fast and each number shall be returned only once.

My current approach is:

- Create a `std::vector` containing the numbers from 0 to 800
- Pick a number using `numberVector[rand() % numberVector.length()]`
- Delete this number from the vector

I have to do this very often and my current approach is slow. Is there some way to speed things up here?

Comment: Did you search for e.g. "generate unique random numbers"?

Comment: No, I missed that term. But thanks! Brings me further!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create a `std::vector` containing the numbers from 0 to 800
2. Shuffle the vector.
   This should be useful: [c++ - How to shuffle a std::vector? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926433/how-to-shuffle-a-stdvector)
3. Take the elements of the vector one by one, from the head to the tail. You don't have to delete the element: just store the index of last used element.

Comment: Thanks for that approach! I like it! But wouldnt it be better for speed to use this approach with a normal array?

Comment: @Nidhoegger: Vectors *are* normal arrays underneath the hood.

Comment: Yes, but by filling it up with 800 values, I would have 800 allocations, right? I could create an array with 800 values in one allocation. Thats my thought. But I dont know, I guess Ill make a benchmark :)

Comment: @Nidhoegger: If 800 is known at compile-time, then you can also use `std::array`. But I don't think you will notice a speed difference.

Comment: @Nidhoegger: With `std::vector`, you don't have 800 allocations. You can have as little as 1 allocation if you reserve all memory in advance. Even if you `push_back` one element after the other starting with an empty vector, the vector would grow more intelligently, resulting in only a few allocations in total.

Comment: You can use `reserve()` to allocate enough memory to `std::vector`. Note that this differs from resizing (adding/removing elements).

Answer (score 1):

1. std::shuffle (std::random_shuffle) your std::vector
2. pop_back elements

Comment: Note to new readers:  `std::random_shuffle` was deprecated in C++14 and removed in C++17. Don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

> Delete this number from the vector

You're probably doing too much work for this. Remember, for example, that deleting from the end of the vector is a lot faster than deleting from the front of the vector.

Since you don't care *where* in the vector your numbers are, you can speed things up by moving the number you want to delete to the end of the vector; e.g.

```
int take_from_vector(vector<int> &vec, size_t pos)
{
    int rv = vec[pos];
    swap(vec[pos], vec.back());
    vec.pop_back();
    return rv;
}
```

---

However, if you're generating just a few things, it is probably faster to use *rejection sampling*: you keep track of which numbers you've generated, then reject any repeats. e.g.

```
int generate_another_number(set<int> &already_generated, int bound)
{
    while (true) {
        int rv = rand() % bound;
        auto pos = already_generated.insert(rv);
        if (pos.second) { return rv; }
    }
}
```

Depending on how many things you're generating, you might want to use `unordered_set<int>` instead of `set`. Or maybe even use `vector` and just iterate over the vector to see if it contains the generated number.

---

P.S. consider using C++'s random number generation features, rather than the ancient `rand()` function.