# How Would I randomly iterate through a loop

Tags: c++, loops, random

I set up a program where I have two kinds of characters: players and enemies, and I inserted two players into a list and two enemies into another list. Now I have a loop merging two lists. What I'm not sure how to do is make it so every loop has the players and enemies turn set to random. So the order of the turns is always different. Could someone help me figure out how to set the order of players and enemies randomly in this loop?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Character.h"
#include "Weapon.h"
#include "PlayerCharacter.h"
#include "EnemyCharacter.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <list>

using namespace std;



void playerAttack(Character* c1, Character* c2, Weapon w, string target)
{
if (target == "1")
{
    cout << "Attack Enemy 1" << endl;
    c1->takeDamage(w.Damage);
    if (c1->healthPoints <= 0) 
        c1->die();
}
else if (target == "2")
{
    cout << "Attack Enemy 2" << endl;
    c2->takeDamage(w.Damage);
    if (c2->healthPoints <= 0)
        c2->die();
}
else if (target == "1" && c1->isDead())
{
    cout << "Attack Enemy 2" << endl;
    c2->takeDamage(w.Damage);
    if (c2->healthPoints <= 0)
        c2->die();
}
else if (target == "2" && c1->isDead())
{
    cout << "Attack Enemy 1" << endl;
    c1->takeDamage(w.Damage);
    if (c1->healthPoints <= 0)
        c1->die();
}
}

void enemyAttack(Character* c1, Character* c2, Weapon w)
{
srand(time(NULL));
int randTarget = (rand() % 2 + 1);
if (randTarget = 1 || c2->isDead())
{
    cout << "Attacks Player One" << endl;
    c1->takeDamage(w.Damage);
    if (c1->healthPoints <= 0)
        c1->die();
}
else if (randTarget = 2 || c1->isDead())
{
    cout << "Attacks Player Two" << endl;
    c2->takeDamage(w.Damage);
    if (c2->healthPoints <= 0)
        c2->die();
}
}




int main()
{

srand(time(NULL));  

PlayerCharacter* p1 = new PlayerCharacter;
PlayerCharacter* p2=new PlayerCharacter;
EnemyCharacter* e1 = new EnemyCharacter;
EnemyCharacter* e2 = new EnemyCharacter;

Weapon p1W = p1->currentWeapon;
Weapon p2W = p2->currentWeapon;
Weapon e1W = e1->currentWeapon;
Weapon e2W = e2->currentWeapon;

string enemyTarget, playerTarget;

p1->printCharacter();
p2->printCharacter();
e1->printCharacter();
e2->printCharacter();

list<Character*> players;
list<Character*> enemies;

list<Character*>::iterator PinsertIt = players.begin();

list<Character*>::iterator EinsertIt = enemies.begin();




for (; PinsertIt != players.end() && EinsertIt != enemies.end(); 
++PinsertIt, ++EinsertIt)
{
    players.push_back(p1);
    players.push_back(p2);

    enemies.push_back(e1);
    enemies.push_back(e2);
}
```

Comment: generate a random integer x in the range of your list size and then get the x element from that list

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926433/how-to-shuffle-a-stdvector

Comment: @koulini i guess OP wants each index only once per game turn.

Comment: A straightforward way would be to [shuffle](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) a container with the players and enemies. However, this is better done with a `std::vector` of your pointers instead of a `std::list`.

Comment: You have 2 empty lists you are trying to iterate

Comment: You have six possibilities: ppee, pepe, peep, eepp, epep, eppe.  Generate a random number in the range 0-5 to select one of the possibilities.