# c++14 - Is there any difference between vec.begin() and begin(vec)

Tags: c++, syntax, c++11, iterator, c++14

In this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926433/how-to-shuffle-a-stdvector) user703016 used the following syntax for accessing the iterators of vector cards_:

For C++98 they recommended using: cards_.begin() and cards_.end()

For C++11 they recommended using: std::begin(cards_) and std::end(cards_)

For C++14, which syntax is preferable, and is there any real difference between the two? Prior to today I've only seen the first syntax.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote I received 10 seconds after posting this question? Please comment saying how I can improve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you're dealing with a `vector`, it makes no difference which you use.

`std::begin()` and `std::end()` will, however, work in some situations where `.begin()` and `.end()` won't work. The primary one is working with a built-in array. For example, this will work fine:

```
char foo[] = "17395";

std::sort(std::begin(foo), std::end(foo));
```

Of course `foo.begin()` and `foo.end()` can't possibly work, since a built-in array doesn't have any member functions.