# How to generate nine digits numbers in which each digit differ from the others

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am making a program and I need to generate all 9 digits numbers which have each digit different to the other digits, the 0 is not a valid digit in this case so I am only considering digits from 1 to 9.

So far I have this solution using random number generation, but I am facing performance issues

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    srand (time(NULL));

    int secret;
    string number = "";

    map <string, bool> m;
    int count = 0;

    int nine_permutation = 362880;

    vector <int> v{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int x = 9;

    while(count < nine_permutation)
    {
      for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
      {
          secret = rand() % x +1;
          number += to_string(v[secret]);
          v.erase(v.begin() + secret);

          x--;
      }
      x = 9;
      v = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
      if(m.count(number) == 0)
      {
        m[number] = true;
        count ++;
      }


      cout << count << endl;
    }


    cout << number;
}
```

Comment: What performance issues; where did you find the bottleneck?

Comment: The program suddendly stops generating after 43,000 numbers aprox. Then it crashes and I have to close it via Task Manager because the window is completely frozen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to shuffle a std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926433/how-to-shuffle-a-stdvector)

Comment: Read about `std::next_permutation`.

Comment: Generating all permutations by random is going to take a while – especially using `rand` and `%, since your random digits aren't uniformly distributed. Be systematic instead of random.

Comment: Crashing is not a performance issue.

Comment: Reading more closely, you're not even generating nine-digit numbers - print `number` inside the loop and look.

Comment: I suggest you to shuffle your vector as describe here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926433/how-to-shuffle-a-stdvector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have 10 digits `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` and number you want to get numbers with nine digits.
I think you can start with `123456789`, generate all permutations and then replace each character with '0' which would give set:
`{023456789, 103456789, 120456789, 123056789, 123406789, 123450789, 123456089, 123456709, 123456780}`. And for each element from this set also generate all permutations.
Something like this:

```
void allNumbersWithDistinctDigits() {
    int idxForZero = 0;
    std::string initial("123456789");

    std::string local(initial);
    do {
        while (std::next_permutation(local.begin(), local.end())) {
            if (local[0] != '0') {
                std::cout << local << std::endl;
            }
        }
        local = initial;
        local[idxForZero] = '0';
    } while(++idxForZero <= initial.size());

}
```

Condition `if (local[0] != '0')` is optional and it gets rid of numbers starting with `0`, like: `012345678` which is in fact 8 digits `12345678` or octal number.